# select a word in table between 2 commas php is not working

Tags: php, mysql

first my mysql table land is: NL,BE,DE,AF
i want to explode first than i want the exploded words if it is equal to the options value than select that options

```
$resultxx = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page where page_id = '$page_id'") or   die(mysql_error());
$number=mysql_num_rows($resultxx); 
    while($land = mysql_fetch_array($resultxx)){ 
     $exp = explode(',', $land['land']);
     }


$count = 0;
//Check if space exists in substrings
foreach ($exp as $code) {
  if (strpos(trim($code), ' ') == false) { //strpos better for checking existance
      $count++;
      $land = constant(COUNTRY_.$code);
        ?>
<option selected value="<?php echo $code; ?>"><?php echo $land; ?></option>
     <?php
  }}
 ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: What does `not working` mean?

Comment: You should look into using MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements, the old mysql_ functions have been deprecated.

Comment: the <option> is not working with selected. i want to select all de options is equal to the exploded word. its a multi select dropdown

Comment: Are COUNTRY_AF etc strings? Or where are you setting them? Also with that second while loop, you will be printing 3 options per value found in $exp. Not that it makes a difference but you could use a foreach loop instead of the second which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$land['land']` is a string like 'AF,BE,NL,DE' then you get array. You can loop through array using `foreach` like this:

```
foreach($exp as $val){
  if ($val == 'AF') {/*do something*/}
  if ($val == 'AR') {/*do something*/}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<select class="multi" multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
  <?php

$resultxx = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page where page_id = 1") or       
 die(mysql_error());

 $number=mysql_num_rows($resultxx); 
    while($land = mysql_fetch_array($resultxx)){
     $exp = explode(',', $land['land']);

?>
<option <?php if(in_array("AF",$exp)) echo "selected='selected'"; ?> value="AF"><?php echo COUNTRY_AF; ?></option>

<option <?php if(in_array("NL",$exp)) echo "selected='selected'"; ?> value="NL"><?php echo COUNTRY_NL; ?></option>


<option <?php if(in_array("DE",$exp)) echo "selected='selected'"; ?> value="DE"><?php echo COUNTRY_DE; ?></option>

</select>

<?php }
```

Comment: Please avoid the use of mysql as its already deprecated and would be removed in newer version of php. Instead use mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could do it?
Just make sure you define all the countries in an array `$countries`. How you do it doesn't matter but since I don't know where you get the country list, I defined it at the top.

```
<select class="multi" multiple="multiple" id="my-select" name="my-select[]">
    <?php

    $countries = array('AF', 'NL', 'DE', 'BE');
    $resultxx = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM page where page_id = 1") or       
    die(mysql_error());

    $number=mysql_num_rows($resultxx);

    while($land = mysql_fetch_array($resultxx)){

        $exp = explode(',', $land['land']);

        for($i = 0; $i <= count($countries); $i++){ 
            ?>
            <option<?php echo in_array($countries[$i], $exp) ? ' selected' : '' ?> value="<? print $countries[$i]; ?>">
                <?php echo constant('COUNTRY_'.$countries[$i]); ?>
            </option>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
```